# What is the purpose of these If statements with conditional logic?

Tags: vb.net

I do not understand this logic with VB. I have seen one example with a constant:

```
Enum Turnos
    Ninguno = 0        'nothing    the  constant is =        0
    Desayuno = &H380   'breakfast  the  constant is =      896
    comida = &H1E000   'lunch      the  constant is =   122888
    Cena = &HE00003    'dinner     the  constant is = 14680067
end Enum

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Es la hora {0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now)
    Console.WriteLine("Turno: {0:G}", QuéTurnoEsAhora())
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Public Function QuéTurnoEsAhora() As Turnos
    Dim ahora As Integer = CInt(Math.Pow(2, DateTime.Now.Hour))
    If (ahora And Turnos.DESAYUNO) <> 0 Then Return Turnos.DESAYUNO
    If (ahora And Turnos.COMIDA) <> 0 Then Return Turnos.COMIDA
    If (ahora And Turnos.CENA) <> 0 Then Return Turnos.CENA
    Return Turnos.NINGUNO
End Function
```

When using the following function

```
'If (ahora and Turnos.DESAYUNO) <> 0 then  returns Turnos.DESAYUNO
```

My questions is why (ahora And Turnos.DESAYUNO)) is <> 0 ?? And the next function

```
'If (ahora And Turnos.COMIDA) = 0'
```

I'm sorry I do not understand which is the logic. Could someone help me?

Comment: Why are you using `Math.Pow`?

Comment: Rather than asking for a tutorial on code you dont understand, why dont you explain *what* you are trying to do?

Comment: Your structure `&H...` is NOT correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your constants in the Enum are a bit mask, which overlap with certain hours of the day according to the meal which should be eaten.

For instance, Breakfast which has a hex value of 380 and decimal value of 896, has a binary value of (24 bits) 000000000000001110000000. Counting from the least significant and starting at zero, the 7th, 8th, and 9th bits are high. As noted in another answer, a bitwise and is used to mask the current hour with this value. The result is 1 only when the current hour is equal to 7, 8, or 9.

The same goes for the other meals. There is an error in your comment for lunch, which should be decimal 122880, not 122888.

Here is a table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `And` here acts as a [bitwise and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator).
I think a simpler example might help you understand it:

```
Enum bitwiseExample
    Empty = 0      ' 0000
    One = 1        ' 0001
    Two = 2        ' 0010
    Four = 4       ' 0100
    Eight = 8      ' 1000
EndEnum

Dim x as integer = 6 ' 0110

x and bitwiseExample.Empty = 0  ' since 0110 & 0000 = 0000
x and bitwiseExample.One = 0    ' since 0110 & 0001 = 0000
x and bitwiseExample.Two = 2    ' since 0110 & 0010 = 0010
x and bitwiseExample.Four = 4   ' since 0110 & 0100 = 0100
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar now is clear for me again thansk very much.